# Ruby on Rails form action submitting to /object.1 instead of just /object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

https://gist.github.com/781133

I've got a form that should be submitting to "/site/:id/detail", but when I look at the form action it says "/site/:id/detail.1" and after hitting the update action (I don't use create from the web so I can't test that) ends up at "/site/:id/detail.1" but I need it at "/site/:id/detail".

I've included the form, the update action and the routes for my application.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with how Rails handles path helpers. When you create a singular `resource` route, it still creates the `resource_path` helper, but it doesn't expect an object argument because it's a singular resource, not a collection. When you pass in the @path object, its ID is used as the format of the generated path.

Instead of `redirect_to resource_path(@resource)` use `redirect_to resource_path` where "single_resource" is the name of the model that this structure is based on.

So in your code, you would want to switch this section to the following…

```
if @detail.update_attributes(params[:detail])
  format.html { redirect_to(site_detail_path, :notice => 'Details Updated!') }
  format.js { render :layout => false}
else          
  format.html { redirect_to(site_detail_path, :notice => 'Details Not Updated.') }
  format.xml { head :ok }
end
```

Comment: I tried making this chamge to no effect. I'm not sure the problem is in the controller since the action on the form is incorrect before the controllerb ever gets involved

Comment: Ahh yeah you need to change your form as well: `form_for @resource, :url => resource_path do |f|`